# How to get the value in the gridview which the checkbox is checked?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview, checkbox

Hi i have a grid view  which has a checkbox column...

when ever the user checks and clikcs on the button
this is how my grid Looks

```
         checkboxColumn|ID|CustomerNAme
      --------------------------------------
                        1|asjd
                        2|asdfas
                        3|asdjka

                assign(Button)
```

When user checks the required rows i want to get only ID value of grid and stoer into database

```
       protected void BtnAssignWork_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < GrdCustomerData.RowsInViewState.Count; i++)
    {
        GridDataControlFieldCell cell = GrdCustomerData.RowsInViewState[i].Cells[0] as GridDataControlFieldCell;
        CheckBox chk = cell.FindControl("Chkselect") as CheckBox;

        if (chk.Checked == true)
        {
            var allIDs = (from item in GrdCustomerData.Rows.Cast<GridRow>()                              
                          let id = int.Parse(item.Cells[1].Text)
                          where chk.Checked
                          select id).ToList();
            using (var myconn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
            {
                foreach (var id in allIDs)
                {
                    using (var mycomm = new SqlCommand("SP_AssignedWork", myconn))
                    {
                        myconn.Open();
                        mycomm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        mycomm.Parameters.Add("@LoanID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = id;
                        mycomm.Parameters.Add("@EmpID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DDLSelectEmployee.SelectedValue;
                        mycomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        myconn.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

can any one help me with this....

Comment: i got the control evry thing is fine now....but on insertion its taking all the ids..where it has to take the id of only checked column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any ways i solved my answer....

here is the code i hope it may be helpfull to some one....

```
    void grid1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == GridRowType.DataRow && GrdCustomerData.RowsInViewState.Count > 0)
    {
        GridDataControlFieldCell cell = e.Row.Cells[0] as GridDataControlFieldCell;
        CheckBox chk = cell.FindControl("Chkselect") as CheckBox;

        GridDataControlFieldCell cellInViewState = GrdCustomerData.RowsInViewState[e.Row.RowIndex].Cells[0] as GridDataControlFieldCell;
        CheckBox chkInViewState = cellInViewState.FindControl("Chkselect") as CheckBox;

        if (cell.Value == chkInViewState.ToolTip)
        {
            chk.Checked = chkInViewState.Checked;
        }
    }
}

protected void BtnAssignWork_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string LoanIds = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < GrdCustomerData.RowsInViewState.Count; i++)
    {
        GridDataControlFieldCell cell = GrdCustomerData.RowsInViewState[i].Cells[0] as GridDataControlFieldCell;
        CheckBox chk = cell.FindControl("Chkselect") as CheckBox;

        if (chk.Checked == true)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(LoanIds))
               LoanIds += "";

           LoanIds = chk.ToolTip;
                    SqlConnection myconn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
                    SqlCommand mycomm = new SqlCommand("SP_AssignedWork", myconn);
                    myconn.Open();
                    mycomm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    mycomm.Parameters.Add("@LoanID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = LoanIds;
                    mycomm.Parameters.Add("@EmpID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DDLSelectEmployee.SelectedValue;
                    mycomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    myconn.Close();
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this an answer or additional informations to your question? If the latter, it should be included into your question. If it is the former, then it's a copy of my answer but with additional code that should be removed. The code in my answer is complete for your `BtnAssignWork_Click`. You are iterating all rows again what makes no sense because the LINQ query and the `foreach` already does.

Comment: in your answer i waz not able to find the checkBox control..where as in my answer now i can.....your answer waz corect to thats the reason i upvoted you...any way i have still have a flaw in your answer var allids is taking all th ids...

Comment: Anyway, your code does not make sense or at least my LINQ query does not anymore. If you want to avoid LINQ you could simply keep your loop, get the id by `id = int.Parse(item.Cells[1].Text)`. But then you should remove the LINQ and the foreach(your outer loop is looping alls rows with checked checkboxes). The only thing that was not working apparently was the way you get the reference to the checkbox in an Obout Grid. (see my edited answer, especially the added `Cells[0]` in the LINQ query)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`SelectedIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindex.aspx) property to get the currently selected row, then get the cell you want from that row. Something like:

```
 GridViewRow row = CustomersGridView.SelectedRow;
 int CustomerId = int.parse(row.Cells[2].Tex);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using a `TemplateField` and a `CheckBox` with `ID="Chkselect"`:

```
protected void BtnAssignWork_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    var allIDs = (from item in GrdCustomerData.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>()
                 let chk = (CheckBox)item.Cells[0].FindControl("Chkselect")
                 let id = int.Parse(item.Cells[1].Text)
                 where chk.Checked
                 select id).ToList();

    using(var myconn = new SqlConnection(connstring)){
         myconn.Open();
         foreach (var id in allIDs) { 
            using(var mycomm = new SqlCommand("SP_AssignedWork", myconn)){
                mycomm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                mycomm.Parameters.Add("@LoanID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
                mycomm.Parameters.Add("@EmpID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(DDLSelectEmployee.SelectedValue);
                mycomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
         }
     }
 }
```

**Edit**: Just for clarification, i've joinded together both parts. You don't need an additional row-loop since the LINQ query already does.

Comment: Hi...i edited my answer can u check that..i am getin error at this line.." if ( chkGrid.Checked == true)" saying object refernce not set to an insatnace of an object

Comment: @Anil: I've also edited my answer, have you seen it? Apart from that i cannot tell you more since you haven't shown the aspx markup, but the row-loop in your button-click handler is redundant with the LINQ query(`allIDs` already contains all selected ID's).

Comment: geting the same error object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: i got the control evry thing is fine now....but on insertion its taking all the ids..where it has to take the id of only checked column...

Comment: You should edit your original question and add there what you have so far. What code have you used? Does my LINQ query work as expected? It should only list all IDs that belong to the checked rows.

Comment: your query is listing all the ids of the grid....not only checked once but unchecked once two

Answer (score 0):

Use Gridviewrows class to find the current row from that use cell[1] which represent the control at that cell from that u can get the id